# Eliminar una pregunta porque el problema que pregunta es diferente al que se suponía

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Tengo la duda de si eliminar una pregunta porque la fuente de los problemas que intenta solucionar al final son diferentes al que se suponía.

Me explico. Hace unos días tenía un problema para recibir información en una app que lee de una cola de mensajes. Es un desarrollo en Python sobre Azure Service Bus.

Pues bien, al formular la pregunta pensaba que el problema era del código Python que no estaba bien, pero finalmente creo (o más bien intuyo) que el problema es de la herramienta Azure Service Bus, a la que le exijo cosas que no puede hacer

En este caso, ¿qué hago? ¿Elimino la pregunta o espero que algún experto en Azure Service Bus me lo confirme? Lo digo por no mantener una pregunta que no se si puede ser de utilidad a la comunidad.

Comment: [Tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98175/recibir-informaci%C3%B3n-de-una-subscipci%C3%B3n-a-un-topic-en-azure-service-bus) parece interesante. Dale tiempo para que alguien con conocimientos de Azure te ayude. También puedes ofrecer [una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para que alguien se anime a investigar y ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: Si el planteamiento inicial de tu pregunta no era correcto, tienes dos opciones: Editar tu pregunta para añadir tus descubrimientos posteriores y aclarar mas la pregunta, o eliminarla y crear una nueva pregunta que ya contenga de principio el planteamiento y la información adecuados. Yo me inclinaría por la primera.

Comment: Como me han comentado tmb en SoFEs, voy a esperar a asegurarme de que el problema es de la herramienta, no del código, y entonces veré cómo actuar, porque quizá no tenga sentido tenerla tal y como esta, como tú propones @Pikoh

Comment: Como te ha comentado @Pikoh, editaría la pregunta con tus nuevas suposiciones y la dejaría a ver si alguien te ayuda